# What is the formula to use if I want to write on an up and down arrow?

Tags: commutative-diagrams

Please how can I get to write `$p_1$` and `G` like in the figure, I know how to write on a rightarrow, but I'm stuck on the up and down arrow.

[image]

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you already have. On this site we generally do not like "please make this for me"  kind of questions, users should at least show some effort. In this case I'd use the `tikz-cd ` package, the manual basically explains how to make these, and they look better hø than in the image (the lower arrow is too short in my opinion)

Answer (score 1):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\spt}{spt}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
U\times F\arrow{r}{f}\arrow{d}[swap]{p_1} & \spt N(V)\subset V\times F \\
U \arrow{r}{pr} & M^{n-1}\arrow{u}[swap]{G}
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]